# div inside a gridview itemtemplate

Tags: asp.net

How do I create and control the content of a div inside a cell of an itemtemplate in  a gridview?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your div and id and runat="server" then use the rowdatabound event

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

You'll then need to find your div within each row based on the id and make whatever changes you need

Oh and don't forget to use this within your rowdatabound event or you'll grab headers, footers, etc and not be able to find your control in there

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
```