# max-width:100% isn't working

Tags: css, html-table

I have a gridview table on my page that is expanding way beyond the page width, even though I have max-width:100% set in several places. Here is my custom css for the table (it is in the .gridTable class):

```
gridTable{
   border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border-spacing: 0; 
   float:left;
   table-layout: fixed;
   max-width: 100% !important;                       
}
```

There is one column that has very long data, and causes the table to become too wide. I have tried to restrict that by hiding overflow:

```
div.gridTable tbody > tr > td:nth-last-child(2) {
   max-width:100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

However, even with all of this, my table still extends past the page width when I have long data in that column. When I inspect the element, I can see that it has all of the max-width:100% style restrictions, and even some inherited from the bootstrap.css file for the table class, but for some reason they aren't doing anything; it just expands as much as it needs to and adds a scroll bar.

Everything works if I set the width for the one problem column to a fixed number of pixels, but obviously I don't want to do that because it should be a different size depending on the size of the screen.

EDIT:
This isn't the same question as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021098/prevent-element-from-expanding) because the solution to that question was to add word-break:break-word in order to break the lines to be the right size. However, that causes them to wrap onto another line, and I don't want any wrapping, I want to hide the overflow. When I include code to hide the overflow, as I am currently doing, the word-break:break-word code does not change anything.

EDIT 2: I'm defining my table from a DataTable dt, and binding the data in the code behind:

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class="gridTable">
  <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" >
</asp:GridView></div>
```

Comment: can you please make and share a jsfiddle?

Comment: What happens when you remove white-space: nowrap ?

Comment: `float` requires a width element from which the max-width is then compared. A float with just a max-width is a bit like having a mortgage but not having a house. Without `width` the float becomes `inline-block` and will expand to fit its contents

Comment: and your `max-width` doesn't need the `!important` remove it.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi, if I take that out then it is the correct width, but there is overflow, which I do not want. I'd rather the overflow was hidden, and the only I've managed that is to include the nowrap part.

Comment: @Martin I tried taking out the float line, but the table still goes beyond the page. Do you have any suggestions for how to keep it within the page width?

Comment: Use Chrome inspector or Firefox Firebug to assesss the page structure and applied CSS

Comment: `max-width` doesn't work on `table-cell` element. Post the HTML as well so we can see how it looks like

Comment: @LGSon I don't think it's the same problem as that question that you mentioned as a possible duplicate, because I don't want to break my lines--I want to include the white-space:nowrap, which negates the effect of the word-break that was the solution to that question.

Comment: @issharp: So you want the text to hide when overflowed?

Comment: @LGSon yes, that's exactly what I want

Comment: @issharp: Then _GL.awog_ as the answer for you...right?

Comment: @LGSon I don't think so, because I don't want to set all of my columns to a % width. They're all slightly different sizes, so I can't split them evenly. Also, I want the data in them to always be visible. However, if I set them to a certain %, the size will be much different-- 10% on a mobile device is much smaller than 10% on a desktop, so I'm worried that the data wouldn't be visible on some devices if I took that approach. What I'm saying is, certain columns should be 10% on a desktop, but 20% on mobile, and this final column should change size to take up the remaining space.

Comment: @issharp: So what should happen to the content when it doesn't fit, as you say it can't break line and shouldn't hide??

Comment: @LGSon Oh, no, sorry if that was unclear--I do want it to hide on this final column that is of variable length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a trick that I tested in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11, with success.

Dropping the `table-layout: fixed` and then setting the width to 1px, makes the first column to size to its content.

Adding a div to the second column, giving it a width of 1px, will make its overflow visible kick in, and that seems to not push the column beyond the table's width.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v0p633yz/1/)

```css
.gridTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 80%;
}
.gridTable td {
  border: red solid 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gridTable td:first-child {
  width: 1px;
}
.gridTable div {
  max-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table class="gridTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td><div>
      Col 2a Col 2a Col 2a Col 2a Col 2a 
      Col 2b Col 2b Col 2b Col 2b Col 2b 
      Col 2c Col 2c Col 2c Col 2c Col 2c 
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not exactly. Like I said, I don't want to set the width of the first column to a percent, I'd rather have it be only as wide as necessary, depending on the data inside. And then have the second column be exactly as you have it, where it expands to fill the rest of the space.

Comment: @issharp Updated my answer

Comment: Yes, that looks like it's doing exactly what I want! My question now is, how can I create a div for that second column, when I'm defining my table in the code behind (see the edit I just made that has the code).

Comment: @issharp That is a completely new question. I suggest you accept the one that does solve your original question and then create a new one asking that (and I will point you to a couple of existing answers)

Comment: @issharp Actually, you could have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719479/div-inside-a-gridview-itemtemplate and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719965/dynamically-change-the-class-of-a-div-nested-in-a-gridview-item-template-from-co

Comment: Thanks--those are helpful. I'm still not 100% sure how to go about it--I made a separate question, if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210219/add-div-to-gridview You've been really helpful already so obviously don't feel like you need to spend any more time on this.

Comment: @issharp My point having you post a new question, properly tagged and targeted, is that there will very likely be a few ASP pro's out there who will know how to go about that part, which I don't. That way you get best possible input on each step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116576/discussion-between-issharp-and-lgson).

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you:

```
td {
   word-break: break-word;
}
```

This is what I did when I had a long URL inside a `td` and the URL wasn't breaking itself and forces the table to expand way beyond the page width.

Here's a link to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021098/prevent-element-from-expanding).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's not the same as the problem I'm having; see the edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add width for each td in the first row. the total sum of their widths should result in 100%. If you have 3 equal columns then 33.33% width for each of them, if 4 = then 25%, if they are unequal than calculate the right percentage for them.

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k15yrL0f/1/)**

Plus assign 100% width for the table and  overflow:hidden for tds in order to hide large content.

```
.gridTable{ width:100%}
.gridTable td {overflow:hidden;}
```